# What is $f(x)$ if $f(x) +xf(-x)=x+1$?

Tags: calculus

I am trying to find the functional equation of $f(x)$, where $f$ satisfies
$$
f(x) +xf(-x)=x+1.\tag{1}
$$
There is no further information.

I attempted inverting the equation $f^{-1}(f(x)) = x = f^{-1}(x(1-f(-x))+1)$ but it doesn't seem to lead anywhere. I also tried plugging random $x$ values in order to understand the problem better, but still I could find nothing interesting.

Any ideas?

Comment: Inverting is not usually a good idea since you don't know if $f$ is a bijection. Try making the change $x\mapsto -x$.

Comment: Substitute $-x$ Into $x$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By replacing $x$ with $-x$ in (1) we get
$$f(-x)-xf(x)=-x+1\Leftrightarrow f(-x)=x(f(x)-1)+1.$$
Therefore, by plugging it into (1), we find
$$f(x) +x^2(f(x)-1)+x=x+1$$
that is
$$(x^2+1)(f(x)-1)=0$$
and we may conclude that $f(x)=1$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Presumably this is for real $x$.  It seems to be possible for $f(i)$ to take any value in which case  $f(-i) = if(i)-i+1$

Comment: @Henry Yes, If $x\not=\pm i$ then $f(x)=1$. Given the value of $f(i)$ then $f(-i)=i(f(i)-1)+1$.  Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 4):

Plug in $-x$ to get
$$\tag2f(-x)-xf(x)=-x+1.$$
Now you have two linear equations in two unkowns $f(x)$ and $f(-x)$.

Answer (score 4):

Change $x$ to $-x$ to get $f(-x)-xf(x)=1-x$. Multiply by $x$ to get $xf(-x)-x^{2}f(x)=x(1-x)$. Substitute for $xf(-x)$ from the original equation and solve for $f(x)$.